# Returning a reference of STL container element

Tags: c++, stl, reference, containers

A blog I came across at http://developer-resource.blogspot.com.au/2009/01/pros-and-cons-of-returing-references.html writes:

> After working in this code base for a while now I believe that
>   returning references are evil and should be treated just like
>   returning a pointer, which is avoid it.
>
> For example the problem that arose that took a week to debug was the
>   following:

```
class Foo {
        std::vector< Bar > m_vec;
      public:
        void insert(Bar& b) { m_vec.push_back(b); }
        Bar const& getById(int id) { return m_vec[id]; }
      }
```

> The problem in this example is clients are calling and getting
>   references that are stored in the vector. Now what happens after
>   clients insert a bunch of new elements? The vector needs to resize
>   internally and guess what happens to all those references? That's
>   right there invalid. This caused a very hard to find bug that was
>   simply fixed by removing the &.

I can't see anything wrong with the code. Am I misunderstanding return by reference & STL containers, or is the post incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say for example you have 2 elements in the vector:

`a` and `b`. You return references for these `r1` and `r2`.

Now another client does an insert into the vector. Since the vector has only two element storage present. It reallocs the storage. It copies `a` and `b` and inserts `c` after them. This changes the locations of `a` and `b`. So references `r1` and `r2` are now invalid and are pointing to junk locations.

If the getById method was not return by reference a copy would have been made and everything would have worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is more easily displayed as:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(1);
const int& ref = vec[0];
vec.push_back(ref);
```

The contents of `vec[1]` are undefined. In the second `push_back`, `ref` is reference to wherever in memory `vec[0]` was when it was initialized. Inside of `push_back`, the `vector` might have to reallocate, thereby invalidating what `ref` refers to.

---

This is a major inconvenience, but luckily, it isn't a problem that happens all too often. Is `Foo` a container people insert the same `Bar` they just found by ID? That seems funny to me. Incurring a copy on every access seems like overkill to solve the problem. If you think it is bad enough,

```
void insert(const Bar& b)
{
    if ((m_vec.data() <= &b) && (&b < m_vec.data() + m_vec.size()))
    {
        Bar copy(b);
        return insert(copy);
    }
    else
        m_vec.push_back(b);
}
```

In C++11, it would be much better to write `Foo::insert` like so (assuming `Bar` has a decent move constructor):

```
void insert(Bar b)
{
    m_vec.emplace_back(std::move(b));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other answers, it's worth pointing out that this effect depends on a container type. For example, for [vectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xd04bzs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) we have:

> Vector reallocation occurs when a member function must increase the
>   sequence contained in the vector object beyond its current storage
>   capacity. Other insertions and erasures may alter various storage
>   addresses within the sequence. In all such cases, iterators or
>   references that point at altered portions of the sequence become
>   invalid. If no reallocation happens, only iterators and references
>   before the insertion/deletion point remain valid.

while [lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/802d66bt%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) are more relaxed in this regard due to their manner of storing data:

> List reallocation occurs when a member function must insert or erase
>   elements of the list. In all such cases, only iterators or references
>   that point at erased portions of the controlled sequence become
>   invalid.

And so on for other container types.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment of the same article:

> The issue here is not that returning by reference is evil, just that
>   what you are returning a reference to can become invalid.
>
> Page 153, section 6.2 of "C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and
>   Reference" - Josuttis, reads:
>
> "Inserting or removing elmeents invalidates references, pointers, and
>   iterators that refer to the following elements. If an insertion causes
>   reallocation, it invalidates all references, iterators, and pointers"
>
> Your code sample is as evil as holding a reference to the first
>   element of the vector, inserting 1000 elements into the vector, and
>   then trying to use the existing reference.