# use of & while creating object of structure

Tags: c++, object, structure

Suppose I have a program

```
struct node
{
    int bot,el;
    char name[16];
};

int main()
{
  stack < node > S;
  node&b = S.top;
  return 0;
}
```

What does the `&` in `node&b` mean?

Comment: It means `b` is a [reference variable](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/references.html) of type `node`.

Comment: [Read about references](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/references.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should fix the call to `top`:

```
node &b = S.top() ;
```

So at this point `b` is now an alias to the top element in the stack so any changes you make to `b` will be reflected for the top element in the stack as well. Taking reference to elements in a standard container can be [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732843/returning-a-reference-of-stl-container-element) and so you understand the implications. This code demonstrates the principle, while staying as close to your example code as possible:

```
int main()
{
  std::stack <node> S;

  node n1 ;

  n1.bot = 10 ;
  n1.el  = 11 ;

  S.push(n1) ;

  node a  = S.top() ; // a is a copy of top() and changes to a won't be reflected
  node &b = S.top() ; // b is now an alias to top() and changes will be reflected

  a.bot = 30 ;
  std::cout << S.top().bot << std::endl ;
  b.bot = 20 ;
  std::cout << S.top().bot << std::endl ;

  return 0;
}
```